# path parameter not being populated from UI

Tags: openapi, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I'm using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 6.5.0

viewtype=full
widgetguid=940FFD66-A7C2-42F5-AAA2-153CBF9136EE

In Swagger UI when I execute an API call with both path parameters populated it produces this:

https://localhost:7168/api/widget/{viewtype}/940FFD66-A7C2-42F5-AAA2-153CBF9136EE

i.e. it replaces one token but not the viewtype token

I can't see why and there are no errors in the browser console.

```
    "/api/widget/{viewtype}/{widgetGuid}": {
                "get": {
                    "tags": [
                        "widget"
                    ],
                    "parameters": [
                        {
                            "name": "viewType",
                            "in": "path",
                            "required": true,
                            "schema": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "widgetGuid",
                            "in": "path",
                            "required": true,
                            "schema": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "format": "uuid"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "responses": {
                        "200": {
                            "description": "Success",
                            "content": {
                                "text/plain": {
                                    "schema": {
                                        "$ref": "#/components/schemas/widgetDtoFull"
                                    }
                                },
                                "application/json": {
                                    "schema": {
                                        "$ref": "#/components/schemas/widgetDtoFull"
                                    }
                                },
                                "text/json": {
                                    "schema": {
                                        "$ref": "#/components/schemas/widgetDtoFull"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
```

Comment: Can you post your controller declaration with annotations? There seems to be a letter case mismatch - the route uses `{viewtype}` (with lowercase `t`) but the actual parameter name is `viewType` (with uppercase `T`).

Comment: you are correct that was the problem - thank you

Answer (score 0):

Helen correctly pointed out a case mismatch - TY

viewtype Vs viewType